# How to re-arrange images in default WP Gallery more than one image at once?

Tags: images, gallery

Im using default WP gallery with custom output. Thank's to that I don't need other gallery plugin. But if I have a lot of images, re-arranging images is very arduous process, cause I can move only one image at once. Is there any possibility to modify WP gallery to re-arranging group if images, instead one after one?

Comment: It would probably require a lot of custom code. Are you using the new Block Editor gallery or the old Editor's gallery? The new one is faster for dragging and dropping images right in the Editor (rather than the Media modal).

Comment: No, I'm using classic editor so Editor's gallery...